# Convert bytes to hex value

Tags: python, serial-port

I have this 32bit value b'F6F3F6F2' arriving in the serial port from an MCU and would like get the two 16bit values that are in there, F6F3 and F6F2 so that I can feed them to the im.putpixel function.

```
s = serialPort.readline()
s = s.split(b'\n')
print(s[0])  # prints b'F6F3F6F2'
#...
im.putpixel((x,y),((F6F3&0xF800) >> 8, (F6F3&0x07E0) >> 3, (F6F3&0x001F) <<3)) 
im.putpixel((x,y),((F6F2&0xF800) >> 8, (F6F2&0x07E0) >> 3, (F6F2&0x001F) <<3))
```

I can't change the way the MCU sends this data so I have to do this on the python side which I am not that familiar with.

thanks

Comment: Please provide a simple example for a valid input and your expected output.

Comment: You should look into the `from_bytes()` method of `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte_value = b'F6F3F6F2'
high, low = byte_value[0:4], byte_value[4:]
print(high, low)

# Convert high, low into int
high_int = int(high, 16)
low_int = int(low, 16)

print(high_int)
print(low_int)

# now you can use those values like
im.putpixel((x,y),((high_int&0xF800) >> 8, (high_int&0x07E0) >> 3, (high_int&0x001F) <<3)) 
im.putpixel((x,y),((low_int&0xF800) >> 8, (low_int&0x07E0) >> 3, (low_int&0x001F) <<3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from colormap import rgb2hex
from colormap import hex2rgb

print(rgb2hex(255, 255, 255))
print(hex2rgb('#FFFFFF'))

>>> #FFFFFF
>>> (255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?